# Change in angle effect on azimuth and dip

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spheres

I'm working with 3d points connected by arcs which could be fit onto a sphere, and when joined together always result in a smooth curve. I have the location of all points and the arc length between them, and can calculate the chord length and rate of change of the azimuth and dip between points.

I'm trying to figure out the azimuth and dip at each point so that the series of xyz points can instead be represented by a series of azimuth, dip and depth. I've worked out the radius and angle of the arc and think the deviation between the line directly to the next point and the real path is half the angle of the arc. I'll use the rate of change of azimuth and dip directly between points to find the proportion of the deviation in the azimuth and dip direction.

How can I find the deviation in azimuth and dip between the direct path and the deviated path? If the direct dip is 50°, direct azimuth 40°, only the azimuth is changing and the arc angle is 20°, how would I determine the resulting azimuth and dip?

Comment: A $20$-degree arc with a (relatively) large radius will be much longer than an $20$-degree arc with a much smaller radius, so I think you're going to have to keep track of more information about the arcs than just "azimuth, dip, and depth". (Direction of curvature makes a big difference too!) Also, what do you mean when you say "the direct dip is $50^\circ$" but "only the azimuth is changing"?

Comment: Azimuth, dip, and depth should be enough. I just realised depth was an unclear word, depth here means the total length of the curve going between points.

Comment: On the second point I mean the dip between successive points is constant, but the azimuth between them is changing, so the direction of curvature will go out in the azimuth direction to keep the curve smooth.

Comment: Why do you call it "direct" dip if it's just the dip at each endpoint? The endpoints are the same for the direct path and for the arc, isn't that right?

Comment: By direct I mean the angle of the chord to the next point, which can be calculated easily from changes in xyz. The actual angle will be different though because the curve deviates from the direct straight line between points by half the angle of the arc.

Comment: What I don't know is how that deviation modifies the direct dip and azimuth to find the real ones. If there's no change in z between points and dip starts off flat it would be easy, change in azimuth = half arc angle. But if the dip is say 80 degrees I don't know how to find the change in azimuth and dip.

Comment: I still don't understand how this fits together. I think you need either a picture or some other reference to describe this.

Comment: OK, I think if I give you a real world context it will be easier to understand. There's a well through the ground which is measured at stations along the way with values for x, y, z and length of the well from the start to that point. All sections of well are a shape such that they would fit on a sphere. I'm converting the description of the well from x, y , z and depth to dip, azimuth, depth, again with all sections between points being curves which could fit onto a sphere.

Comment: How are the $x,y,z$ coordinates defined? Is the point $(0,0,0)$ at the center of the Earth, or somewhere else? Presumably these are the kinds of wells that don't go straight down, but presumably they don't go at a constant distance below sea level, so in what sense do they "fit on a sphere"?

Comment: x y and z are just a normal cartesian coordinate system. Z could be meters below ground and x and y some level of north and east. The shape of the well between points will be an arc which could fit on the surface of some sphere. I say fit on a a surface of a sphere so you know that the curvature is constant.

Comment: OK, I'm not trying to be difficult, but I think most people would say "circular arc" rather than "an arc which could fit on the surface of some sphere". The "sphere" made me think that all the arcs would fit on the surface of the _same_ sphere, or that the azimuth and dip were some variation of spherical coordinates around a fixed center. It's now clear neither of these are desired at all. In fact I am starting to doubt that you even want to model the curvature of the surface of the Earth, which could have been approximated by a sphere. It might be better if you didn't mention spheres at all.

Comment: By "depth" I guess you mean total length of the curve/path. (I can imagine this might make sense in well-drilling; I can't think of any other model or application in which that word might be used that way.) By "smooth" I guess you mean the first derivative is continuous--there are no sharp corners or kinks--not that the curve is mathematically smooth. I think you also still need at least one more piece of information; the dip at the start of the well might be sufficient. Otherwise I think there are multiple paths that could connect the points as described.

Comment: By the way, once you figure out how you really want to describe this problem to other people who don't already know exactly what you have in mind, it's OK (in fact, very desirable) for you to use the "edit" link under the question text to change the wording of the question.